# Python, how to make a new line when a new number is used

Tags: python

```
for x in range (0,13):
  for y in range(0,13):
    print(x,'X',y,'=',x*y," ",end="")
```

My output of my code:

```
0 X 0 = 0  0 X 1 = 0  0 X 2 = 0  0 X 3 = 0  0 X 4 = 0  0 X 5 = 0  0 X 6 = 0  0 X 7 = 0  0 X 8 = 0  0 X 9 = 0  0 X 10 = 0  0 X 11 = 0  0 X 12 = 0  1 X 0 = 0  1 X 1 = 1  1 X 2 = 2  1 X 3 = 3  1 X 4 = 4  1 X 5 = 5  1 X 6 = 6  1 X 7 = 7  1 X 8 = 8  1 X 9 = 9  1 X 10 = 10  1 X 11 = 11  1 X 12 = 12  2 X 0 = 0  2 X 1 = 2  2 X 2 = 4  2 X 3 = 6  2 X 4 = 8  2 X 5 = 10  2 X 6 = 12  2 X 7 = 14  2 X 8 = 16  2 X 9 = 18  2 X 10 = 20  2 X 11 = 22  2 X 12 = 24  3 X 0 = 0  3 X 1 = 3  3 X 2 = 6  3 X 3 = 9  3 X 4 = 12  3 X 5 = 15  3 X 6 = 18  3 X 7 = 21  3 X 8 = 24  3 X 9 = 27  3 X 10 = 30  3 X 11 = 33  3 X 12 = 36  4 X 0 = 0  4 X 1 = 4  4 X 2 = 8  4 X 3 = 12  4 X 4 = 16  4 X 5 = 20  4 X 6 = 24  4 X 7 = 28  4 X 8 = 32  4 X 9 = 36  4 X 10 = 40  4 X 11 = 44  4 X 12 = 48  5 X 0 = 0  5 X 1 = 5  5 X 2 = 10  5 X 3 = 15  5 X 4 = 20  5 X 5 = 25  5 X 6 = 30  5 X 7 = 35  5 X 8 = 40  5 X 9 = 45  5 X 10 = 50  5 X 11 = 55  5 X 12 = 60  6 X 0 = 0  6 X 1 = 6  6 X 2 = 12  6 X 3 = 18  6 X 4 = 24  6 X 5 = 30  6 X 6 = 36  6 X 7 = 42  6 X 8 = 48  6 X 9 = 54  6 X 10 = 60  6 X 11 = 66  6 X 12 = 72  7 X 0 = 0  7 X 1 = 7  7 X 2 = 14  7 X 3 = 21  7 X 4 = 28  7 X 5 = 35  7 X 6 = 42  7 X 7 = 49  7 X 8 = 56  7 X 9 = 63  7 X 10 = 70  7 X 11 = 77  7 X 12 = 84  8 X 0 = 0  8 X 1 = 8  8 X 2 = 16  8 X 3 = 24  8 X 4 = 32  8 X 5 = 40  8 X 6 = 48  8 X 7 = 56  8 X 8 = 64  8 X 9 = 72  8 X 10 = 80  8 X 11 = 88  8 X 12 = 96  9 X 0 = 0  9 X 1 = 9  9 X 2 = 18  9 X 3 = 27  9 X 4 = 36  9 X 5 = 45  9 X 6 = 54  9 X 7 = 63  9 X 8 = 72  9 X 9 = 81  9 X 10 = 90  9 X 11 = 99  9 X 12 = 108  10 X 0 = 0  10 X 1 = 10  10 X 2 = 20  10 X 3 = 30  10 X 4 = 40  10 X 5 = 50  10 X 6 = 60  10 X 7 = 70  10 X 8 = 80  10 X 9 = 90  10 X 10 = 100  10 X 11 = 110  10 X 12 = 120  11 X 0 = 0  11 X 1 = 11  11 X 2 = 22  11 X 3 = 33  11 X 4 = 44  11 X 5 = 55  11 X 6 = 66  11 X 7 = 77  11 X 8 = 88  11 X 9 = 99  11 X 10 = 110  11 X 11 = 121  11 X 12 = 132  12 X 0 = 0  12 X 1 = 12  12 X 2 = 24  12 X 3 = 36  12 X 4 = 48  12 X 5 = 60  12 X 6 = 72  12 X 7 = 84  12 X 8 = 96  12 X 9 = 108  12 X 10 = 120  12 X 11 = 132  12 X 12 = 144
```

I need the line of code to be printed out each time on a new line.

the output i need:

```
0x0=0 0x1=0 0x2=0 0x3=0 0x4=0 0x5=0 0x6=0 0x7=0 0x8=0 0x9=0 0x10=0 0x11=0 0x12=0
1x0=0 1x1=1 1x2=2 1x3=3 1x4=4 1x5=5 1x6=6 1x7=7 1x8=8 1x9=9 1x10=10 1x11=11 1x12=12
2x0=0 2x1=2 2x2=4 2x3=6 2x4=8 2x5=10 2x6=12 2x7=14 2x8=16 2x9=18 2x10=20 2x11=22 2x12=24
3x0=0 3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15 3x6=18 3x7=21 3x8=24 3x9=27 3x10=30 3x11=33 3x12=36
12x0=0 12x1=12 12x2=24 12x3=36 12x4=48 12x5=60 12x6=72 12x7=84 12x8=96 12x9=108 12x10=120 12x11=132 12x12=144
```

basically like this but through the whole multiplication process

Comment: So you need a new line once there are no more `y`s to iterate over...

Answer (score 2):

You could do it at the end of each iteration of the outer loop:

```
for x in range (0,13):
    for y in range(0,13):
        print(x,'X',y,'=',x*y," ",end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i wasnt adding this line to the outerloop that was my problem i kept adding it to the inner loop

Answer (score 2):

Add `print('')` in outer loop:

```
for x in range (0,13):
  for y in range(0,13):
    print(x,'X',y,'=',x*y," ",end="")
  print('')
```

Comment: Or just `print()`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 for x in range (0,13):
  for y in range(0,13):
    print(x,'X',y,'=',x*y," ",end="")
    if y == 12:
        print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range (0,13):
    for y in range(0,13):
        print(x,'X',y,'=',x*y," ",end="")
    print('\n')
```